# Group action on a space over a division ring $D$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

I am confused about very basic thing.

Let $V$ be a right $D$ module where $D$ is a division ring. Suppose that a group $G$ acts on $V$ (from right) linearly and faithfully.

If $D$ is a field, we can say that $V$ is a $DG$ module where $DG$ is a group ring. Now suppose that $D$ is not a field.

Can we say that $V$ is a right $DG$ module? What I think is that :

Since $G$ can be embedded into the multiblicative group of the ring $End_D(V)\cong M_n(D^{op})$, can we say that $V$ is a right $D^{op}G$ module?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I would think it's more natural for $G$ to act on $V$ from the left. After all, you want the action to be $D$-linear. Like
$$g\cdot(x\alpha)=(g\cdot x)\alpha$$
for all $g\in G$, $x\in V$ and $\alpha\in D$? Somehow this feels more natural for the purposes of makind the actions of $G$ and $D$ commute with each other.

Comment: Hmm. As you discuss $DG$ may be you do want $D$ and $G$ to commute anyway.

Comment: The normal convention in this situation is to let $G$ act on one side and $D$ on the other. So $G$ can act on the right and then $D$ should act on the left. That ensures that the actions are commutative i.e. $(dv)g = d(vg)$ for $d,v,g \in D,V,G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt does that jive in this case though?  If you had a right $D[G]$ module you’d recover a right $G$ action and right $D$ action, and that this would be inverse to building the $D[G]$ action from the two actions.  Not clear there’s a related left G action… unless they’re regarded as $G^{op}$ actions and that is the same  as a $G$ action since $G$ is anti isomorphic via the inverse map?  I don’t doubt what you’re saying I’m just trying to fit it in here.  I too am used to considering V as and End(V),D bimodule with actions on opposite sides.

Comment: I think a left $D$-action combined with a right $G$-action probably can be reformualted as a right $D^{\rm op}G$-module. I am more familiar with $(KG,KH)$-bimodules, where $K$ is a (commutative) field, and you have a left $G$-action together with a right $H$-action. These arise in a number of contexts. They can be reformulated as right $K(G^{\rm op} \times H)$-modules, and a clever equivalent trick is to define a right $G$-action by setting $vg = g^{-1}v$.

Answer (score 1):

I think $D$ is an $DG$ module, and not necassirily $D^{op}G$ module.

Because in a group ring $RG$, the elements of $G$ and $R$ "commutes". The action of $G$ and $D$ on $(D,+)$ commutes as $G\subseteq End_D(V)$, and so these two actions can be extended to the action of group ring $DG$ in a compatible way.

This may not be possible for $D^{op}$ and $G$ as thay are bot subset of $End_D(V)$, they do no necassarily commutes. So, their action may not be extended to $D^{op}G$ in general.

Comment: I was going to say as much... Have you not checked the obvious action?  In many cases I would have expected that to be the first thing done.  The heuristic in the second paragraph is fine, but it doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thank you for your comment. If you write an ecaxt proof, I would happily accept it as an accepted answer. I could not see a practical way to write it. This  would be definitly more benefcial for each reader.

Comment: I don’t see anything tricky about it. It is just routine verification. You should give it a shot yourself.

Comment: @rschwieb: I did infact.